# route.params returning undefined on console log

Tags: javascript, react-native, routes, react-native-navigation

i want to call the route.params from the uid in Appstack,
console.log(route.params) shows undefined
I've used the same uid in search screen to show all the users logged in, when i call the listener to navigate to post, an error " cannot read the property of uid" is shown

```
const Profile = ({currentUser, posts, route, navigation}) => {
  const [userPosts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const {uid} = route.params.uid;
  console.log(route.params);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uid === firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid) {
      setUser(currentUser);
      setUserPosts(posts);
    }
```

This would be my stack

```
  <Tab.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={SearchUsers}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.push('Profile', {
            uid: firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid,
          })
        }
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Icon name="search-outline" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStack}
        initialParams={{uid: firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid}}
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          headerShown: false,

          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Icon name="person-outline" color={color} size={size}/>
          ),
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Please post code and not links to screenshots-of-code.  You can add code to your post either using the "code block" widget in the editor or by typing a line consisting of just three backticks (\`), then your code on its own lines, then finish with another line consisting of just three backticks(\`)

Comment: @GregFenton Hi, i'm sorryy i'm new don't really know how to post the code, because it shows me the error of 4 spaces

Comment: Can you show how you are navigating to your Profile component, and passing parameters with that navigation?  It should be something like `navigation.navigate('Profile', {uid: 86});` to pass the value `86` for the parameter `uid`.  This is as per the example on this page: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Comment: @GregFenton 
 onPress={() =>
          navigation.push('Profile', {
            uid: firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid,
          })
        }

Comment: Use of `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not a good idea since the login process is asynchronous.  Your code might be calling `firebase.auth().currentUser` before the login has completed (login continues well past clicking the "sign in" button in your app).  This is why the `onAuthStateChanged()` function exists.  It starts up a "listener" in your app and gives you the `user` value when the login process has completed.  You are best to capture that value from onAuthStateChanged() into a state variable of your own and use that instead of `....currentUser`.

Comment: To share code, I use this syntax: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: @GregFenton its still the same `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe you want to join a Firebase discussion forum such as "Firebase Me" on discord or the "Firebase Community" Slack workspace where you can have an iterative discussion?